# Changing Drupal's default email notification on password reset

Tags: users

I need to change the text the user gets in the email with the one time login url. How can I do that?
By the way, say I want to generate a login url from my module, is that possible?
I'm using drupal 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pop to http://www.mysite.com/admin/user/settings, you can edit the subject and body for the email under the "Password Recovery Email" fieldset.

To do this programatically you can call [`_user_mail_notify()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/_user_mail_notify/6) with the `password_reset` op parameter:

```
_user_mail_notify('password_reset', $account);
```

You can generate a one-time login link using the [`user_pass_reset_url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_pass_reset_url/6) function:

```
$url = user_pass_reset_url($account);
```

Comment: about the first one, thank you! about the second question, i asked about generating the url login for my script, not sending the email notification...

Comment: @Moshe Sorry about that I've updated the answer with the function you need to use to generate the one-time login link

Comment: In Drupal 7 the link is: /admin/config/people/accounts